# Updating Table But Keeping One Existing Data

Tags: mysql

I'm working on these tables:

```
staff(staffID, staffName, branchID, address, phone, lastUpdatedDate)
branchRef(branchID, branchName)
```

To generate report on staff details categorised by branch

```
SELECT staffID, staffName, staff.branchID, address, phone, lastUpdateDate, branchName
FROM staff, branchRef
WHERE staff.branchID=branchRef.branchIC
```

For example what if, John is in Branch01 in year 2011 and Branch03 2012. How do preserve the (Branch01, 2011) when updating to (Branch02, 2012). I've read that using trigger to do the job, trigger involves in almost all of the fields but I only wish to keep a record of the old branchID. Is there any suggestion to this problem? Thank you!

Comment: You can add one extra column called Active_flag in your staff table and maintain the history records...

Comment: @Jamie: Do you want to keep a history of previous branches or just the actual one for an employee?

Comment: I want to keep a record of previous branches for employees when they get transfered to a new branch. So you can keep track of his/her previous branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you have a one-to-many relationship: One staff member has one branch, but one branch has many staff members.

If a staff member will now be able to be part of more than one branch (even as history, as you said in your comment), then the relationship will become a many-to-many relationship. Apart from that I **think** you want to get the other branches in order so what you could do is the following:

Keep your current tables just as they are, but removing branchId from staff:

```
staff(staffID, staffName, address, phone, lastUpdatedDate)
branchRef(branchID, branchName)
```

Create a new table `staff_branches` that will hold the relationship between them:

```
staff_branches(staffID, branchID)
```

The primary key of the table will be both fields. Now you should implement an order of those tables. If you just care about the order, just add an integer field that would hold that order (1, 2, etc). If you want to get additional information (like the date in which the staff member started in that branch), just use a date for the orderField:

```
staff_branches(staffID, branchID, orderField)
```

Once you've done that, you can query for the current branch for an employee by searching in that table for the branch with the max(orderField) for that staffId.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to update your data model.

It doesn't take into account the possibility that a staff member might switch branches.c

Triggers won't help you with this problem.

You could:

- make a new table `staff_member_works_in_branch`, with fields like `start_date` and `end_date`, `staffId` and `branchId` to represent the new m:n relationship.  Your report may have to be updated. **(recommended solution if you're going to be doing this often)**
- keep the records of moved staff members data outside of the database
- implement a kludge with "fake" employee rows (not recommended)